# ObjectMapper fails to deserialize - cannot deserialize instance of .... out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a json like this:

```
{
  "games": [
      {
        "id": "mhhlhlmlezgwniokgawxloi7mi",
        "from": "425364_456@localhost",
        "to": "788295_456@localhost",
        "token": "xqastwxo5zghlgjcapmq5tirae",
        "desc": "6CeF9/YEFAiUPgLaohbWt9pC7rt9PJlKE6TG6NkA4hE=",
        "timestamp": 1412806372232
      },
      {
        "id": "62jzlm64zjghna723grfyb6y64",
        "from": "425364_456@localhost",
        "to": "788295_456@localhost",
        "token": "xqastwxo5zghlgjcapmq5tirae",
        "desc": "Z/ww2XroGoIG5hrgiWsU1P8YHrv4SxiYHHoojzt9tdc=",
        "timestamp": 1412806373651
      }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize it to an Object with `ObjectMapper`. Essentially as you can see, it is a List of games.

I have classes like these:

```
@JsonRootName(value="games")
public class GameJson{
    private List<Game> games;
// getters and setters

}
```

the Game class is here:

```
public class Game{
    private String id;

    private String from;

    private String to;

    private String token;

    private String desc;

    private Instant timestamp;

    // getters and setters
}
```

In my code, the `ObjectMapper` is doing this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

GameJson json = mapper.readValue(
                       new FileInputStream(gamesFile), GameJson.class);
```

Then I get this error:

*Can not deserialize instance of `com.games.collection.GameJson` out of `START_ARRAY` token*

I am trying different ways to do this, but coming out with no luck. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of

```
@JsonRootName(value="games")
```

That annotation identifies the annotated type as the target for the JSON object mapped to a JSON key named `"games"`. In your case, that is a JSON array. An array cannot be deserialized into your `GameJson` class.

[As you stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302613/objectmapper-fails-to-deserialize-cannot-deserialize-instance-of-out-of-s/26302658#comment41273867_26302658), you also need to remove the configuration that enables `@JsonRootName`.

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me how it's an array and not a List?

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri It's a JSON array. A JSON array can be deserialized into a `Collection` type (`List` or `Set`) or into a Java array.

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri Jackson is trying to deserialize the array called `games` into a `GameJson` object instead of the root JSON into `GameJson`.

Comment: That makes sense. I've tried what you said, but it still didn't work. I removed 
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
 and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri Ah yes, I missed that part of your config. You're welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. See ya around!